# how add actions a grid of product in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, grid

Can I get help with this issue?

How you can add another action in the product grid in Magento 2?

I tried doing an overwrite but does not show expected, overwrites the block `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Grid` in the file `di.xml`:

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Grid" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Producto\RewriteGrid" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can create an `after` plugin for `Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\ProductActions::prepareDataSource()`.

add this in the `di.xml` of your module:

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\ProductActions">
    <plugin name="my-plugin-name" type="[Namespace]\[Module]\Plugin\ProductActions" sortOrder="10" />
</type>
```

then create the file `[Namespace]/[Module]/Plugin/ProductActions.php`

```
<?php
namespace [Namespace]\[Module]\Plugin;
class ProductActions
{
    protected $context;
    protected $urlBuilder;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface $context,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlBuilder
    )
    {
        $this->context = $context;
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
    }
    public function afterPrepareDataSource(
        \Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\ProductActions $subject,
        array $dataSource
    ) {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            $storeId = $this->context->getFilterParam('store_id');

            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as &$item) {
                $item[$subject->getData('name')]['do_something'] = [
                    'href' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(
                        'catalog/product/do_something',
                        ['id' => $item['entity_id'], 'store' => $storeId]
                    ),
                    'label' => __('Do Something'),
                    'hidden' => false,
                ];
                $item[$subject->getData('name')]['do_something_else'] = [
                    'href' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(
                        'catalog/product/do_something_else',
                        ['id' => $item['entity_id'], 'store' => $storeId]
                    ),
                    'label' => __('Do Something else'),
                    'hidden' => false,
                ];
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Marius, it works; a question, this is the right way to make this work.

Comment: I cannot say for sure but it seams like the way to go.

Comment: From everything I'm seeing the other answer is correct and this is functional but mistaken. Sorry Marius

Comment: @LM_Fielding. The other answer describes how to add a NEW column that contains an action. Using mine you will get the actions as a dropdown in the same column. This is more inline with the other magento grids. I guess it's just a matter of preference.

Comment: Isn't it best practise to merge in changes via the jsLayout or xml?

Apologies,  the information is very limited. Can you make any edit to your answer so I can change my vote?

Comment: Plugins are non intrusive either. I won't edit the answer unless i spot a typo or something. Leave your vote like it is. You are entitled to your oppinion. No hard feelings.

Answer (score 2):

> Create ui_component/store_settings_listing.com and add below
>   actionColumn element under columns node

```
<columns name="store_settings_columns">
        <actionsColumn name="actions" class="MageMastro\Store\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\StoreActions">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">107</item>
                <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">200</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </actionsColumn>
</columns>
```

Create UI Action Class

MageMastro\Store\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\StoreActions.php

```
/**
 *
 * @package MageMasto Store custom actions
 * @author  Harshad Pandit <magemastro@gmail.com>
 * @created 2016-02-09
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2016 Harshad Pandit, http://invhub.com.
 */

namespace MageMastro\Store\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;
use Magento\Cms\Block\Adminhtml\Page\Grid\Renderer\Action\UrlBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;

class StoreActions extends Column {

    `/** @var UrlBuilder */
    protected $actionUrlBuilder;

    /** @var UrlInterface */
    protected $urlBuilder;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $_viewUrl = 'mm_store/*/view';

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $_editUrl = 'mm_store/*/edit';

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $_deleteUrl = 'mm_store/*/delete';

    /**
     * @param ContextInterface $context
     * @param UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory
     * @param UrlBuilder $actionUrlBuilder
     * @param UrlInterface $urlBuilder
     * @param array $components
     * @param array $data
     * @param string $editUrl
     */
    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        UrlBuilder $actionUrlBuilder,
        UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
        $this->actionUrlBuilder = $actionUrlBuilder;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Prepare Data Source
     *
     * @param array $dataSource
     * @return array
     */
    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                $name = $this->getData('name');
                if (isset($item['entity_id'])) {
                    $item[$name]['view'] = [
                        'href' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl($this->_viewUrl, ['store_id' => $item['entity_id']]),
                        'label' => __('View')
                    ];

                    $item[$name]['edit'] = [
                        'href' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl($this->_editUrl, ['store_id' => $item['entity_id']]),
                        'label' => __('Edit')
                    ];
                    $item[$name]['delete'] = [
                        'href' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl($this->_deleteUrl, ['store_id' => $item['entity_id']]),
                        'label' => __('Delete'),
                        'confirm' => [
                            'title' => __('Delete ${ $.$data.title }'),
                            'message' => __('Are you sure you wan\'t to delete a ${ $.$data.title } record?')
                        ]
                    ];
                }
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

Comment: Very good answer, well done.